# Views data export only exporting for current page

Tags: views, 8

I have a view which show Tabular data and i have attached data export on this view which should export in CSV format. The problem is if the data is paginated exportation is only downloading the records on the current page, but I want all records. Is there a way of making it to ignore the pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the data export display you need to set the pager to: `Display all items`. This will return you all the data in your file without pagination.